# Support for adding exchange email account with EMM

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I have tried searching, but it does not seem the question has been asked anywhere.
Is there any way to configure Exchange account from EMM?
I know you can set up POP3/IMAP-mail.
What would have to be done to implement such feature?

Best regards

Comment: Please mention the version of WSO2 EMM server you are using.

Answer (score 0):

EMM can send email invites, and  to send  smtp server needs to exist. we can configure smtp sever via the axis2.xml available within repository/conf/axis2

```
<transportSender name="mailto" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportSender">
        <parameter name="mail.smtp.host">smtp.gmail.com</parameter>
        <parameter name="mail.smtp.port">587</parameter>
        <parameter name="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="mail.smtp.auth">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="mail.smtp.user">synapse.demo.0</parameter>
        <parameter name="mail.smtp.password">mailpassword</parameter>
        <parameter name="mail.smtp.from">synapse.demo.0@gmail.com</parameter>
    </transportSender>
```

based on exchange server support for SMTP your scenario should be possible.

Please refer the below document[1] for configuration to send out emails to users that register with EMM

https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM210/Android+Device